# Jquery: How to ignore/remove all element irrespective of their level after certain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a page like [this](http://adnansiddiqi.me/read.php.html). I have to check element which contains "See Additional". I have done this. Now all I have to do to remove all *HTML* after it. I know jqeuery provides `.nextall()` but it is for elements at same level. What should I do to remove elements irrespective of their levels. Below is my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.get("http://localhost:8000/read.php", function(data, status){
    
    // var data = '<h1>Hi World</h1';
    var html = '<div id="rendered">'+data+'</div>';
    
      
      //Check if it exist, it should be marked out as irrelevant
      see_additional = $(html).find("H2:contains('See Additional')");
      
      if(see_additional.length > 0) {
        console.log('Found it')
        parent = see_additional.parent()
        $(see_additional).addClass("intro") // not working
        console.log(parent.attr('id'))
        //$(parent).addClass('remove')
        // parent.remove();
        //console.log(parent.html())        
        $('#view').html($(html).filter('#rendered').html()) // html viewer
      }
    });
  });
```

Please note this page is one of the examples. It could be any page that contains "See Additional". The reason to do this is that I have to ignore all links if they are found in elements AFTER the element contains "See Additional". One way is to remove but I am not successful in it yet.

Comment: Do you have control over the html generation? This would be the suitable place to decorate link elements after output of the trigger text with a `data-` attribute that could ce accessed through the DOM. Otherwise you might visit all ancestors of the DOM elements containing the trigger text and mark/disable/whatever all link elements in the respective following siblings of the visited nodes.

Comment: @collapsar you mean finding all parents at same level, right?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'after'. In the worst-case, meaning that it refers to the linearized order as seen in the source code, you will need to visit all ancestor nodes and process their respective following siblings in turn.